# Training an object detection model using a pretrained classification model as a feature extractor

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api, google-coral

I have a Coral Dev Board and want to experiment with new models, instead of just the ones available at [the official Coral website](https://coral.ai/models). In the article [on Google's AI blog](https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/11/introducing-next-generation-on-device.html), the authors mention benchmarking an object detection model derived from the classification model presented in the article.

How to use such a model a train one for object detection? So far, I've only used the pretrained ones available in the model zoo. Since now quantization-aware training is possible in TensorFlow 2, can we train a model for Coral in TF2 now?

Comment: Model development, training and optimization are done with Keras and Tensorflow running on server farms full of GPUs or TPUs.  The edge TPU is intended for running small ML inference models in real-time applications, not for training.  Only the last layer of a model can be retrained on chip:  https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/retrain-classification-ondevice-backprop/

Comment: @usbguru, I was curious about the details of training an object detection model based on a feature extractor trained on a different dataset, since I haven't seen the description/code anywhere. I am aware that the Edge TPU device is not intended for training.

Comment: These detection configurations might be a good place to start:  https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs